# JQuery foreach chunk 2 and 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this array:

```
Mike
Blue
Jakob
Red
Luis
Orange
```

executing with this JQuery code:

```
$.each( arr, function( index, value ){
     $( ".div" ).append( "" + value + "" );
    }  
});
```

I would like the each loop to 
 jump every second value. So that the loop would create something like:

```
Mike - Blue
Jakob - Red
Luis - Orange
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$.each`, you can just use a *normal* `for` loop and increment by 2 instead of 1.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2){
    $(".div").append(arr[i] + ' - ' + arr[i+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's [modulo (`%`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator and jQuery's `$.each`'s argument of `index`

```
$.each( arr, function( index, value ){
    if (index%2 == 0) { //0, 2, 4 (mike, jacob, luis)
        $( ".div" ).append( "" + value + "" );
    }  
});
```

Modulo gives the remainder when divided by the given number. For example, `6%2` does `6/2`, then takes the remainder. Since 2 goes into six *exactly* 3 times, the modulo is 0, as there is no remainder.

Thus, any *even* number will return 0 from a modulo with 2. We can use this to check if the index is even (0, 2, 4, 6), which will be *every other* iteration

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$.each( arr, function( index, value ){
    var ival = index+1; // index always starts from 0 So we are adding 1 to start the counter from 1
    if(ival%2 == 0){ // %2 is the modulus of 2, If the value is 0, The counter is now an even number, other wise its an odd number
         $( ".div" ).append( " - " + value + "" );
    }else{
        $( ".div" ).append( "" + value + "" );
    }
});
```

Comment: Why should this work? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Sorry, Hope my updated answer will explain better :)

Comment: It is better, but you really should write the explanation in your answer rather than as code comments, just for clarity sake.

Comment: BTW, that was not my downvote and I see it someone has upvoted your answer.

Comment: No Problem Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could actually reverse your thinking, and append the result of a mapping

```
$( ".div" ).append(arr.map(function(x,i) {return i%2 ? x+' - '+arr[i-1] + '<br/>' : null}))
```

```js
var arr = [
    "Mike",
    "Blue",
    "Jakob",
    "Red",
    "Luis",
    "Orange"
];

$( ".div" ).append(arr.map(function(x,i) { return i%2 ? x+' - '+arr[i-1] + '<br/>' : null }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"></div>
```